# Setting memory permissions in forked process

Tags: linux, process

My goal is to set virtual memory page permissions (as if the forked process called `mprotect`) from the parent process. Can this be done with `ptrace(1)` or by some other magic?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just want to call `mprotect()` from the child?

Comment: I'm migrating a process from a networked machine, page by page.  The fork is necessary to just get a new address space.

Comment: Well, I guess I could still do that, huh?

Comment: Yeah, I'd fork() to get the new address space, and then call mprotect() in the forked process, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *can* be done (via `ptrace()` indeed; `gdb` can do this), but not without a lot of finagling, since in order to call a function in another process, you basically have to setup its registers and stack, etc. for execution, and then continue the process, which will execute the function. One program I know off the top of my head that might have some useful source/methodology for you to look at is [injectso](http://c-skills.blogspot.com/2010/02/new-injectso-debian-proof.html). If you do look at injectso, look at the `inject_code()` functions.

In addition, calling conventions vary by platform, so you'd have to re-jigger your code for each architecture/OS, etc.

Comment: I don't really want to "call" a function - I would prefer to set the data directly in the child's page table.  I guess that would be dangerous to allow, though.  No way to proxy requests to OS from a different process?

Comment: @sholsapp: I don't believe so. I think Windows has this functionality, but with Linux it's usually a hack and involves ptrace.